# Async Plugin Execution Order

Tags: asynchronous, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

If I modify the same record three times, and I have an async plugin listening to the Update message, will the updates be ordered?

I'd expect the updates to be ordered, even if executed asynchronously (properly queued for later execution). If this is the case, I hope the same holds for create and delete messates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With asynchronous plugins the order of execution is not guaranteed, if you want to make the plugins be executed respecting the queue you need to use the *DependencyToken* attribute.

You can find an article here:

[Dependency and Execution Order in Asynchronous Operations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327994.aspx)

Comment: this rules out async plugins then. thank you for your reply. I'll contact MS directly on this. In the meantime I'll accept this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @GuidosPreite I can say that of the tests I ran a while ago, the plugins **will** execute in the order you'd expect them to.

However, just as he says, don't bet your house on it. If you're unlucky, an early thread **can** be executed with more delay than an earlier. And provided Murphy's law, **it will**.

Moreover, the behavior may be different on different roll-ups, servers, days of the week etc. So in short: yes but no.

Comment: besides the cheesy words in bold, I agree with your assessment. this has the nasty sideeffect of disrupting any kind of integration aimed at replicating data from the CRM. and it really makes no sense.

Comment: Why cheesy? Is that perceived as unpleasant?! If so, I'll edit it immediately.   :)

Answer (score 0):

Following diagram shows how the execution order work for plugins & workflows.
[Importance of execution order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCdeG.jpg)

**Conclusion:**
Normally workflows’ default execution order value is “0” & user cannot be defined that value. If user set execution order to “1” in plugin step then real-time workflows will be triggered before the plugins.

If user needs to execute plugin before the real-time workflow then user should have to change execution order to “0” in plugin step.